# Javascript replace() function not working in jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've been using javascript `replace()` with to limit input to digits and a single decimal like this:

```
<input id="dialog-input" type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" \>
```

This works perfectly fine and if I can get dialog content from the existing input like this:

```
<input id="dialog-input" type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" \>
dialog = $( '#dialog-input' ).dialog({ });
```

However, if rendered the input directly as a jQuery object for the dialog like this, the second regex replace seems to fail getting the capturing group and something happens where it will only allow a single character in the input:

```
dialog = $( '<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, \'\').replace(/(\..*)\./g, \'$1\');" \>' ).dialog({ });
```

Why does this work in one case but fail in the other?  I have a hunch that some part of my regex needs to be escaped but I've tried a multitude of variations and nothing seems to work.

Comment: are you sure you can grab DOM element like that ?

Comment: Actually, it works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/dc21k0ju/

Comment: @adeneo - your jfiddle works because it's the exact thing that I said worked.  Please re-read my question.

Comment: @taesu, yes I am sure.  The element is fine, just the regex needs extra escapes for some reason as answered below.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood. They are both horrible anyway, avoid inline event handlers like the plague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double escape your period in the second regex:

```
'...replace(/(\\..*)\\./g, \'$1\');" \>'
```

I would just avoid working with strings:

```
$('<input type="text">').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
}).appendTo('body').dialog();
```

Comment: This works but actually the second period needs to be escaped as well.  I've accepted your answer but please updated it with this correction for the sake of others.  Also, would you mind explaining why the periods need to be double-escaped?  I don't understand this.. thanks!

Comment: should be `replace(/(\\..*)\\./g, \'$1\')`

Comment: @billynoah: Wouldn't `.replace(/\.*/g, '.')` work? As for why, in a string, `\.` is interpreted as an escape sequence. It's not a valid escape sequence, so `\.` just becomes `.`. In a regex, however, `\.` means something different. Since your JavaScript code is inside of a string, to literally get `\.`, you must escape the backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  No that wouldn't work.. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/dc21k0ju/1/.  You can see the intended behaviour here:http://jsfiddle.net/dc21k0ju/.

Comment: Blender - thanks but the revision you made is still not correct.  See my comment above.. you escaped the wrong '.'  should be first and third.

Comment: sorry.. I was under the impression that my edits had to be a minimum length or something.  maybe that's just for questions.